# Trapping a custom error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to trap the following error in a `try`/`exception` block, but as this is a custom module that is generating the error - not generating a standard error such as `ValueError` for example. What is the correct way to catch such errors?

Here is my code:

```
try:
  obj = IPWhois(ip_address)
except Exception(IPDefinedError):
  results = {}
else:
  results = obj.lookup()
```

The most obvious way:

```
except IPDefinedError:
```

gives:

```
NameError: name 'IPDefinedError' is not defined
```

The error returned that I want to check for is:

```
ipwhois.exceptions.IPDefinedError
ipwhois.exceptions.IPDefinedError: IPv4 address '127.0.0.1' is already defined as 'Private-Use Networks' via 'RFC 1918'.
```

Comment: `except IPDefinedError`

Comment: I downvoted this because you did not bother to google 5 seconds. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: `except ipwhois.exceptions.IPDefinedError: `

Comment: @vaultah This was the most obvious, but I got an issue with this.

Comment: @tmoreau I did try this too, but still error.

Comment: @Navonod - can you add the import statements you are using, and preferably a snippet of the module / IPDefinedError exception you attempting to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the import!

I had the import as

```
from ipwhois import IPWhois
```

but I also needed

```
import ipwhois
```

So the following works:

```
try:
  obj = IPWhois(ip_address)
except ipwhois.exceptions.IPDefinedError:
  results = {}
else:
  results = obj.lookup()
```

Comment: I would suggest to only do `import ipwhois`, and then `obj=ipwhois.IPWhois...` Otherwise you're importing twice the class `IPWhois`

Comment: @tmoreau True! that's now what I have, I wanted just to illustrate the problem though so people can see.

Comment: @tmoreau: Not really. Python caches imports, so the first import actually reads from the file, but the second is just returning the cached module from `sys.modules`. Two `import` statements, but only one actual import (that said, the brevity gained by removing the module namespacing probably isn't worth the bother).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick recap. Yes, the error in your question did look like it was likely related to an import issue (as per my comment ;)  ).

```
from pprint import pprint as pp


class IPDefinedError(Exception):
    """Mock IPDefinedError implementation
    """
    pass


class IPWhois(object):
    """Mock IPWhois implementation

    """

    def __init__(self, ip_address):
        if ip_address == "127.0.0.1":
            raise IPDefinedError(
                "IPv4 address '127.0.0.1' is already defined as 'Private-Use Networks' via 'RFC 1918'.")
        self._ip_address = ip_address

    def lookup(self):
        return "RESULT"


def lookup(ip_address):
    """ calculates IPWhois lookup result or None if unsuccessful

    :param ip_address:
    :return: IPWhois lookup result or None if unsuccessful
    """
    result = None
    try:
        obj = IPWhois(ip_address)
        result = obj.lookup()
    except IPDefinedError as e:
        msg = str(e)
        print("Error received: {}".format(msg))  # do something with msg
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = map(lookup, ["192.168.1.1", "127.0.0.1"])
    pp(list(results))  # ['RESULT', None]
```